# Mingw, Cygwin g++, STL set

Tags: stl, g++, set, cygwin, mingw

I tried to remove element from STL set data structure by iterating each element. The problem is that I can't delete each element by iterating set structure. When I tried that way, it just give error message or program is stuck.  When it was happened, I thought it was Mingw's bug, so I tried Cygwin g++; however Cygwin g++ also didn't work.
How should I change the code to delete each element in set structure by using iteration

- MinGw and Cygwin are installed on windows 7 x64 system.

```css
//Tested by using MinGW, Cygwin g++ in Win64 environment

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 set<int> mySet;
 mySet.insert(1);
 mySet.insert(2);
 mySet.insert(7);


/*
    //Works fine
    mySet.erase(1);
    mySet.erase(2);
    mySet.erase(7);
*/



/*
    //Error
 for(set<int>::iterator iter = mySet.begin(); iter != mySet.end(); iter++)
  mySet.erase(iter);

 //Error
    int size = mySet.size();
    set<int>::iterator iter = mySet.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        mySet.erase(iter);
        iter++
    }

*/

    //print out elements in mySet
 for(set<int>::iterator iter = mySet.begin(); iter != mySet.end(); iter++)
  cout << *iter << " ";

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mySet.erase(iter)` invalidates the iterator. Next thing, you attempt to increment this now-invalid iterator, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior. Hint: `erase()` returns a valid iterator to the next element. In any case, if your goal really is to remove all elements, just do `mySet.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

Like Igor Tandetnik sayed `mySet.clear()` will work.
But normally in C++11, `mySet.erase(iter)` should return the following element:

> Return an iterator to the element that follows the last element removed (or set::end, if the last element was removed).

In C++98 it returns nos value, that is why it doesn't work.

Try to pass `-std=c++11`when you'll compile to test.

Source : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/